# Generate Entities FOSMessageBundle & FOSComment Bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have spent 7 straight hours on this. The wife left me working on this before she slept and woke up to the same sight = Frustrated!

The task seems simple, to make FOSMessageBundle work with or without FOSCommentBundle. I first tried both together then one alone by themselves and keep getting the darn same error in all 3 cases.

> FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Declaration of Acme\MessageBundle\Entity\Thread::setCreatedBy() must be compatible with FOS\MessageBundle\Model\ThreadInterface::setCreatedBy(FOS\MessageBundle\Model\ParticipantInterface $participant) in ...\src\Acme\MessageBundle\Entity\Thread.php line 15

Below is line 15.

NOTE: I have read and followed the documentation to the last fullstop. I my code is like for like with the documentation. But why cant it work? I am using latest Symfony 2.5 and clean install of bundles. Any help is eternally appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?php
// src/Acme/CommentBundle/Entity/Thread.php

namespace Acme\CommentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\CommentBundle\Entity\Thread as BaseThread;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\ChangeTrackingPolicy("DEFERRED_EXPLICIT")
 */

class Thread extends BaseThread
{
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message `Declaration of … must be compatible with …` is a generic PHP message, indicating that an overridden method is incompatible with its parent or interface.

Child methods must have exactly the same parameters as their parents, and if a parameter is type-hinted, the [child method must type-hint](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) for the same class.

In your case, it appears that you either don't demand a `ParticipantInterface` compatible object in your `setCreatedBy` method, in which case you'd need to fix it like this …

```php
public function setCreatedBy(ParticipantInterface $Participant)
{
    // …
}
```

… or you're missing the namespace import for `ParticipantInterface`:

```php
use \FOS\MessageBundle\Model\ParticipantInterface;
```

Or both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still have this problem.

Where am I to include the namespace import? Because, doing so in my message.php and/or comment.php do not make a difference (I also cleared my cache) I would want to try this public function but also where to place it. Sadly, I thought the example code from the documentation would work out of the box :(

Comment: In the `Acme\MessageBundle\Entity\Thread` class, as the error message says, in the top area where the other `use` statements are.

Comment: Yes, that is where I put it but still this error. I even deleted the new classes and restored from the backup and added this before generating entities but not avail. I even tried adding a database table first. This is so confusing.

Comment: I have just checked my tread.php after generating entities and found this

    public function setCreatedBy(\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User $createdBy = null)
    {
        $this->createdBy = $createdBy;

        return $this;
    }

Comment: Should I change it or add the line you have given me or any other suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Put it under the `use FOS\CommentBundle\Entity\Thread as BaseThread;` line. By the way, if you would like to learn more about PHP namespaces, have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: Ok, so I changed everything as you suggested and the errors disappeared so here is hoping that it works. Changing everything includes including the namespace imports but also changing all references from say Acme\MessageBundle\Entity\User $message=null to MessageInterface $Participant which came by default when you run generate entities using the code in the documentation.
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/01a-orm-models.md
For now I can mark this as the Answer. Thanks @lxg